# Modular Math in Java (Number Line which Wraps Around)

Tags: java, linear-algebra

I am trying to create a simple function that utilizes [modular arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic). This is essentially a number line that wraps around. Specifically I want to use a Mod 8 number line in Java.

What I want is to compare two numbers between 0 and 7.  I want to subtract these numbers to get a difference score. However, instead of 0-7=-7, I want it to equal 1. The idea being that after you reach 7, the number line wraps around back to 0 (therefore 0 and 7 are only one space across.)

Are there any packages that fit this criterion?

Comment: I think you accepted the answer to this too quickly.  The answer you accepted does not take into account numbers smaller than -7.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't notice that until I checked out the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you need to use the % modulo operator. Perhaps write a set of integer functions which work with modulo math, eg. Modulo plus would be =(a+b) % 8;

Comment: And for dealing with negatives, check the input operands are within range (0-7) and then use the +8 as indicated by Faisal.

Answer (score 6):

how about `((0-7)+8) % 8` ? This should fix up your case.

Note: % is the Modular operator.

Comment: NOTE: what if the number isn't -7, but rather -15?

Answer (score 4):

It appears you want to reverse what negative numbers do with modulos.  Keep in mind that the modulus is the remainder after integer division.  Normally you would have a range that looks like this:

```
-7 -6 -5 -4 -3 -2 -1 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

You want it to look like this for the same series of values:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

If you want to solve for the general case where you can have any negative number (such that it will work for -15, -20, -27 as well as -7) then you have to adjust it after the modulus, like this:

```
int m = x % 8;
m = (m < 0) ? m + 8 : m;
```

Essentially this leaves the positive case alone, and will adjust the negative case so the numbers roll over as you want them to.

An alternative way to do this with straight math is to take the modulus twice:

```
int m = ((x % 8) + 8) % 8
```

The first modulus gives you your expected range from -7 to 7.  The addition adjusts the negative modulus so that it is positive, but of course moves the positive values above 7.  The second modulus ensures that all the answers are in the range 0 to 7.  This should work for any negative number as well as any positive number.

Answer (score 0):

The [modulo operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) is what you want. However, the `%` operator in Java, which is often called modulo, isn't the mathematical modulo. It's rather the remainder operator. The difference is subtle and often irrelevant. It's only important if you have negative parameters like in your case. I think [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) can explain the exact difference.

For you're "wrap around" you need the mathematical version of modulo which sadly isn't implemented in Java for Integer. However, the [BigInteger](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) class has a mod() function which does exactly what you need:

```
BigInteger.valueOf(0-7).mod(BigInteger.valueOf(8)).longValue()
```

It's not pretty but works.

Answer (score -2):

Um... there is the built-in *modulus operator* `%`, which is also present in basically every other language that's at all popular these days.

Comment: Details of how negative numbers are handled vary from language to language. This can be handled with some fairly simple numerical recipes, depending on exactly which behaviour you want.

Comment: Actually, details of how negative numbers are handled vary based on what the operator is. For example, in java, the % operator is NOT a mod operator, but rather defined as a remainder of division. ie `assert(-5 % -2 == -1)` Python however, takes the more mathematical approach to what mod really should be.  Read http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=498178

Comment: ... Uh... I would first off argue that neither mathematicians nor any particular subgroup of computer scientists have exclusive rights to define the term "modulus operator", and second that "what the operator is" obviously depends on what language is being used, so I haven't really said anything wrong. But if @Spencer wants a thorough breakdown, it's probably best to just consult Wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation).

Comment: Then don't call it a modulus operator, especially if the question is in reference to java.  That is misinformation.

Comment: I don't understand why you think it shouldn't be called a modulus operator. What other term exists that anyone ever seriously uses for the `%` symbol in Java, C, Python, etc. ?

Comment: It shouldnt be called the modulus operator because thats not what it does nor is it what its called in the java spec. Read http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html. A detailed reason why its not called mod can be found there too.

Comment: Did you mean to reference something actually in the spec, e.g. http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#24956 ? Either way, I don't see anything approaching what could be called "a detailed reason why it's not called mod", seeing as no reference is made to that term except perhaps indirectly via reference to the `fmod` function. You continue to insist "that's not what it does", implying that there is a reason why one particular definition of "modulus" is superior to another, without even citing your definition.